# How to verify that the code in text field and password exist in my database in Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want to do a project page. My graphique interface is ok. However, after connecting my database and writing this code to verify if my code and password exist in my database, I always get the message of my (else) even if the code exists in the database.

```
private void ok1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    try {
        conn=Test.ConnectDB();
        String Sql="select * from login WHERE 'code' =?and 'motdepasse' =?";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
        ps.setString(2,code1.getText());
        ps.setString(1,passe1.getText());
        ResultSet  rs=ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            con_ret s=new con_ret();
            s.setVisible(true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"welcome");
        } else { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"invalid user or password");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        /*Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);*/
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `code1` belong to parameter `1` and `passe1` belong to parameter `2`?

Comment: ohh thak you i thought it's about they re order in my database but when i change that it works

Comment: Nope, it's about the order in which they appear in the query

Comment: Print to console what values you are getting for code1.getText and passe1.getText. Confirm it’s the answers you’re expecting

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to unquote the column name, ie:

```
select * from login WHERE code =? and motdepasse =?
```

Quote means string literals. If you are curious, you could pass `code` and `motdepasse` as code and password to try if they matched.

Edit:

Also I notice that you are confusing your parameter index. The parameter setting should be:

```
ps.setString(1,code1.getText());
ps.setString(2,passe1.getText());
```

Comment: i delete the quote but i still have the same problem

Comment: You can quote but use the correct quotes. Not single apostrophes but backticks